# Unable to change colorScheme for .actionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Currently the actionSheet adapts to the colorScheme set in device settings, but I want to set it manually.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            showingActionSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Action")
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet) {
            ActionSheet(
                title: Text("Title"),
                buttons: [
                    .destructive(Text("Action 2")) {
                    },
                    .cancel()
                ]
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using these 3 modifiers on the VStack but none seem to affect the actionSheet:

```
.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
.accentColor(.black)
```

Comment: Don't apply the preferredColorScheme to VStack, apply it on the ActionSheet

Comment: you can't apply preferredColorScheme on ActionSheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to get it working using SwiftUI view modifiers. But if you dig out the `UIWindow` then you can set `.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` and that seems to work.

Like this:

```swift
VStack {
    // contents as before
}
.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
.onAppear {
    let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    if let firstWindow = scene?.windows.first {
        firstWindow.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this code work for me thanks

Comment: @KavinduDissanayake I'm pleased to hear it. You are welcome to upvote the answer if you found it helpful ;)